# Adjusting the risk gauge for values over 100%

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make sure that the values above 100% are interpreted as 100% (as in the position of the tick and the title), and the value that is displayed is the one that is inputted. Right now, the gauge doesn't work if I try something like `dangerGauge(182)`.

```
library(dplyr)
dangerGauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0, 10, 35, 65, 90, 100)) {
      require(ggplot2)
      get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
        th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
        th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
        th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
        x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
        y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
        return(data.frame(x,y))
      }

pos_per <- paste(round(pos,2),"%")#create output for gauge with % 

pos <-round(pos,1) #round input value so title below works with decimals 
title <- case_when(
between(pos,0,9.9) ~ "no danger",
between(pos,10,34.9)~ "some danger",
between(pos,35,64.9)~ "moderate danger",
between(pos,65,89.9) ~ "high danger",
between(pos,90,100) ~ "extreme danger") #create title


  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="blue")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="yellow")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[4],breaks[5]),aes(x,y),fill="orange")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[5],breaks[6]),aes(x,y),fill="red")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y))+
    geom_text(data=as.data.frame(breaks), size=5, fontface="bold", vjust=0,
              aes(x=1.1*cos(pi*(1-breaks/100)),y=1.1*sin(pi*(1-breaks/100)),label=paste0(breaks,"%")))+
    annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos_per,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) +
labs(title = title)
}
dangerGauge(82)
dangerGauge(182)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a "case" in the case_when function for values that are above 100.
Maybe like this:

```
title <- case_when(
    between(pos,0,9.9) ~ "no danger",
    between(pos,10,34.9)~ "some danger",
    between(pos,35,64.9)~ "moderate danger",
    between(pos,65,89.9) ~ "high danger",
    pos>=90 ~ "extreme danger") #create title
```

and after that, if pos value is above 100 you need to change it to 100.

```
if(pos>100) pos = 100
```

In order to place the tick at the end of the scala.